# Pop an integer out of a list and keep going until the list is gone?

Tags: python, list, function

I have created a random list and trying to pop a number out by using a `userInput` and keep going but it keeps giving me the error, pop index out of range. Even `.remove()` is not working.

```
import random

hand= []


for i in range(10):
    hand.append(random.randrange(1,10))
print (hand)

userInput = int(input("What card do you want to play? "))

while True:
    if userInput > 0:
        hand.pop(userInput)
```

Comment: When do you expect `while True` to stop? Try `while hand`.

Comment: when the list is gone and all digits are removed

Comment: Why do you expect `while True` to stop when the list is gone? What do you think `True` is?

Comment: And why do you expect that? That's sort of what happens, in that your program crashes at that point, but I imagine you wanted something more controlled.

Comment: I thought it would do the same as keepgoing

Comment: What's "keepgoing"?

Comment: What is `userInput`?  The index of the card to remove?  The value of the card to remove?  What are you doing to ensure that the inputted value makes sense and is range for hand?  Do you realizing that popping a value removes it from the list (the list changes length)?  What happens when you've removed all values?  These are the kinds of questions you should be asking.

Comment: keepgoing is a form of while looping. To say that while these integers are still in the list, keepgoing til the list is empty

Comment: Give the above comment, you should be using `while hand` as @jonrsharpe suggested.

Comment: So "keepgoing" is "while the list isn't empty"? Then *write that condition*. `while True` means "forever".

Comment: "keepgoing is a form of while looping" - In what language? It certainly isn't Python. Making up words as you go along is detrimental to effective communication; please avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

The condition of your while loop has to be determining if the length of the hand list is greater than zero. If it is zero, thus empty, it must stop.

```
import random

hand= []


for i in range(10):
    hand.append(random.randrange(1,10))
print (hand)



while len(hand) > 0:
     userInput = int(input("What card do you want to play? "))
     card = hand.pop(userInput)
     print card
```

Note that pop() removes a value at an index and returns it, so you may want to store the returned value and print it, or do something else with it.

Answer (score 1):

I used @Ajax1234's code, the only thing I changed was instead of specifying the index of the card in the list to remove, I used the value of it. For example if we have the following list:

```
hand = [2, 5, 6, 1, 3, 8, 9]
```

If I wanted to play card number `3`, instead of specifying the index (`4`) I would declare the value of it (`3`).

Here is the code I used:

```
import random

hand= []

for i in range(10):
    hand.append(random.randrange(1,10))
print(hand)

while len(hand) > 0:
     userInput = int(input("What card do you want to play? "))
     hand.remove(userInput)
     print(hand)
```